# Why is gold used in latinum based currency?

Tags: star-trek

Gold pressed latinum is a popular form of currency because the latinum can't be replicated. But why is it pressed into gold?

Gold is not an ideal metal for currency. It's soft and tarnishes, and it is heavy. Any number of more durable substances are available to contain the latinum, so why gold?

Comment: Gold tarnishes? You need to buy a better grade of gold.